# Alternatives for Agile Scrum

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum, team

We started following the Agile Scrum methodology and we have completed about 10 sprints.

One observation I had is that not all in the team are taking up the responsibilities of completing the tasks and user stories by themselves and everytime they have to be instructed or allotted with some tasks. Also the estimate they are giving are not very agile.

There is always a need for someone to look after all the user stories, their completion status, tasks that are yet to be done etc and allot them to team members who are not occupied.

I also feel that we would be able to deliver faster if we had one person who would create tasks and assign them to people along with deadlines to complete them (project manager role).

And this is what I feel is missing in Agile Scrum.

Given that the team is not taking up tasks and not risking to take up tight estimates, what are the alternates that we can look for? Or, are there any provisions in Agile Scrum to fasten things?

Comment: What is it you are looking to get out of adopting scrum?  What were the problems with the old approach, whatever that was?  You need to motivate what you are trying to get out of the whole exercise, and get the team to focus on that.  If you introduced scrum simply because others have, and without any overarching goal, then its likely to suffer subtle hostility from those who get things done.

Comment: we havent faced any issues in the older approach, the project manager typically could get things done before the deadlines. 
we tried adopting to agile because we thought that empowering team members will result in increased productivity. But i couldnt see any value out of it and it is already 5 months of following agile scrum

Comment: So did you believe the team was underproductive, or were you being greedy?  Motivating factors behind decisions is everything in this kind of thing.

Comment: Do you have good user stories/tasks that produce functionality you can demonstrate? What are the consequences for the team if they don't deliver on their commitment for a sprint? Do they have to stand up to the whole company and explain why they can't show any more than two weeks ago?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: Do they really have to stand up in front of the entire company? It sounds very much like public humiliation.

Comment: @user99561: That is indeed what a sprint demo would turn into if you don't have to show anything. The way to avoid it is to make sure you can demonstrate something. If the team promises to deliver something and they can't, then it is the responsibility of the team to explain in the (public) demo why they couldn't meet their promises. They can't shift that to someone else, like a scrum master or manager.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: and what will be the result of this public humiliation? That people in the team are blaming the scrum process and stop with it all togehter? They clearly need coaching, not humiliation.

Comment: @user99561: I agree they need coaching, but they also need to be held to their commitments (and know that when making those commitments).

Comment: @Bart:Are you really that clueless? Software development is not all that predictable. Something that seems like it should take a couple of hours can end up taking days or a month quite easily. Likewise, something that seems like it'll take weeks sometimes gets resolved in hours. An estimate is not a commitment. It is exactly what it is called, AN ESTIMATE. If you expect to treat my estimates as a "Commitment" then EVERY 1 DAY task would have a 1 MONTH "Commitment Estimate". Your suggested practice will lead to nothing but Cr@ppp for software as developers will claim their garbage is done...

Comment: ...even though it is full of bugs. Happy day works. I can claim done then I get to avoid the humiliation and the negative reputation for not meeting my "Commitments". I don't know where this quote came from but if your recommended practice is how your company operates then I can guarantee that your company is exactly the kind where "There is never enough time to do it right, but always enough time to do it over again."

Comment: @Dunk: You clearly haven't worked with Scrum. In Scrum, the team *commits* to delivering a certain set of functionality, with a predetermined level of quality, in the *next sprint*. Not further in advance, only the next sprint (at most a few weeks of work). Also, if your work items are small enough (at most a few days of work) and the estimations recent enough (not more than a few weeks old), the average difference between the estimate and the actual time it takes is low enough that the teams can actually make true on their commitment. That is my experience.

Comment: @Bart:We must work in completely different domains so our experiences don't compare. As I said, I've seen apparently trivial tasks mushroom into month long behemoths. Rare, but does happened from time to time. I suppose if similar tasks have been done time and time again then estimates can be reliable, but then again, why are you developing something time and time again? Automate it. Most stuff we work on is "newish", so sometimes we don't know what we didn't know until we got there. It is unrealistic to recover over a 2 week period. Over months, over/under-estimates cancel not over 2 weeks.

Comment: @Dunk: I work in embedded software. Most often, our stories are quite different in functionality, but comparable in complexity and therefore it is possible to give estimate with high confidence levels. If there is so much uncertainty in the scope/effort of the tasks as you indicate (which is common in research work), Scrum might not be the best methodology for you.

Comment: The beauty of Agile is that when a "what I thought was a two hour task" turns into a "months-long behemoth", it never takes longer than one sprint to acknowledge the under-estimation. When you can't demo the feature, you instead must explain why the feature isn't done. Is this public humiliation? I don't think so. It's simply acknowledging the revealed truth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only looked at agile because you were expecting an increased productivity be aware that agile (/scrum) is not a silver bullet. Yes, self empowered teams can become more productive, but they need help.

So get a coach. Agile is like playing chess. It takes 30 minutes to explain the rules and after that you can start playing. But it takes years to reach a reasonable level as a chess player.

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of sounding a bit cheeky, one alternative is to actually use scrum. You're using something *like* scrum but isn't *actually* scrum.

If you have team members that aren't engaged, it sounds like you need an agile coach to get you past the learning phase.

Comment: agile coach can teach the process but will not change people not willing to play the game. this is more people problem that a process problem